# Probability that a given patient is indeed infected?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have the following problem:

> Patients are tested for a particular disease. For each patient, the result of the test (infected or not) is correct with the probability 0.8. Suppose that 20% of the patients are infected. What is the probability that a given patient is indeed infected if his/her test result shows ‘infected’?

Feels that I need to use the Bayes theorem, but the information about test results confuses me a bit. What is the right solution for this problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Drug_testing. Plug in your numbers.

Comment: That seems like the correct answer, which gives $0.5$. Thank you for the useful link.